# What should get tagged [the-new-52]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should questions about any comic title in the New 52 be tagged with [the-new-52](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-new-52)? Or should it just be used on questions that are specifically about the New 52 series - that is, about continuity issues or comparisons between these and previous volumes?

My vote is for the latter, but I'd like to get some other people's take. Is there precedent with tagging other comic book series that we can follow?

Comment: This seems related: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/528/tagging-for-stargate-franchise-related-questions?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

I'd say it should only be used for:

- those questions general to the New 52 Universes;
- those questions specific to a New 52 representation of a character, i.e. if the New 52 canon is significantly different and the question is about that.  [Who were the 6 people who originally trained Batman in the New 52?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/who-were-the-6-people-who-originally-trained-batman-in-the-new-52) is a great example.

For all-encompassing questions, [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics) works fine and for specific questions the individual comic tags are better.

Answer (score 2):

I created the tag when @BrettWhite was doing the New 52 comic grant last year. My mindset was to use the tag for specific questions regarding the new reboot and anything that could help explain things for that continuity.