# Chris Nolan tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/21051/1109) and i tagged it with [chris-nolan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chris-nolan) because I wanted to make sure that the answer would stay in his Batman movies and not the other Batman movies. The tag then got deleted.

Is this tag unnecessary? Is it too specific?

We have tags for authors all over the place, why can't we have tags for writer/directors?

Answer (score 3):

My thought on the matter in deleting the tag was that the question itself was really about the new three Batman movies.  Chris Nolan wasn't the subject of the question and the question didn't cover multiple Chris Nolan works, assuming his Batman trilogy to be one such work.

Related questions:

[Tagging for stargate/"franchise" related questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/528/tagging-for-stargate-franchise-related-questions?rq=1)

[What should get tagged [the-new-52]?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2048/what-should-get-tagged-the-new-52)

Answer (score 1):

I see where you are going with wanting to keep the answers within the Chris Nolan Batman movies, but you don't need tags to do that. The title and text of your question should define the scope you are looking for.

Tags are for helping people subscribe, ignore, and search; not for setting the scope of your question. Since you already included "Batman" and "Chris Nolan" in the title, adding the tag doesn't help anybody search.